# Integrating $\int (t^2+7)^{\frac{1}{3}}$dt

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

> I have to integrate $\int (t^2+7)^{\frac{1}{3}}$dt

I tried some trigonometric substitution and then rationalisation but didn't get anything

Please provide a hint on how to proceed with this question

Please help!!!

Comment: I don't think you can expect an elementary anti-derivative. Are you sure you're supposed to find one (by hand)?

Comment: Are you sure about the power $\frac 13$ ? This makes the problem very difficult (no closed form solution). I bet for  $\frac 12$.

Comment: No it is 1/3 for sure

Comment: Do you want to bet ? I am sure that, once more, there is a typo in a textbook.

Comment: Any answer is appreciated@StackTD

Comment: It could be, but it doesn't mean that this is impossible integral , though it is hard @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Do you already know about  hypergeometric functions ?

Comment: Amm,, no , I only know about some basic high school function and integrals ,, Is this question not for me @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Not for you if you don't know what [special functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions) are.

Comment: This is why I suspected the typo as soon as I saw the question. Don't worry : you will learn about these ! Cheers.

Comment: The answer is in Gauss' Hypergeometric function form.

Answer (score 3):

Setting $$t=\sqrt{7}\cosh x\implies dt =\sqrt{7}\sinh xdx$$

$$\int (t^2+7)^{\frac{1}{3}}dt = 7^{2/3}\int (\cosh^2x+1)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sinh x\, dx =  7^{2/3}\int  \sinh^{5/3} x\, dx$$

this integral cannot be written as elementary function. It belongs to the class of  [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)

Comment: I tried that , but power is 1/3 , this is not helping for 1/3 power

Comment: I bet this is the hint for exponent $\frac12$.

Comment: This is very fine for $\frac 12$ but $\frac 13$ leads to hypergeometric function, I guess.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici ya I just check it does not an obvious integral

Comment: It does lead to $_2\,F_1$ containing a $\frac23$ which I think is enough to disqualify it as an elementary function, or any simpler form like the complete Gamma function.

Comment: isnt it better to use $t=\sqrt{7}\sinh(x)$ , just asking

Comment: @Isham it will make it worse

Answer (score 0):

Positioning your integral:

\begin{equation}
 \int \left(t^2 + 7 \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\:dt = \int_0^t \left(w^2 + 7 \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\:dw = \int_0^t \frac{1}{ \left(w^2 + 7 \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\:dw
\end{equation}

We can employ the solution that I've spoken to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057298/solving-used-real-based-methods-int-0x-fractk-lefttn-a-rightm-d): 
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^x \frac{t^k}{\left(t^n + a\right)^m}\:dt = \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{k + 1}{n} - m} \left[B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n}\right) -  B\left(m - \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n}, \frac{1}{1 + ax^n}  \right)\right]
\end{equation}

Here $a = 7$, $m = -\frac{1}{3}$, $k = 0$, and $n = 2$. Thus,

\begin{align}
\int \left(t^2 + 7 \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\:dt &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot 7^{\frac{0 + 1}{2} --\frac{1}{3}}\left[B\left(-\frac{1}{3} - \frac{0 + 1}{2}, \frac{0 + 1}{2}\right) -  B\left(-\frac{1}{3}- \frac{0 + 1}{2}, \frac{0 + 1}{2}, \frac{1}{1 + 7t^2}  \right)\right] \\
&= \frac{7^{\frac{5}{6}}}{2}\left[B\left(-\frac{5}{6}, \frac{1}{2}\right) -  B\left(-\frac{5}{6}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{1 + 7t^2}  \right)\right]
\end{align}